# QList to QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qlist, qtablewidgetitem

I'd like to paste all my data I stored in several `QList` variables into one central `QTableWidget`.

I have six `QList<QString>` variables with actually each length of them is 7.
With the help of this routine, I'd like to write each element of my `QList` into a `QTableWidgetItem`. What is the easiest and efficient way to solve this?

```
 for (int ridx = 0; ridx < iRowCount; ridx++ )
 {
        tmptable = resultTable[ridx];
        for (int cidx = 0; cidx < iColumnCount; cidx++)
        {
          QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();

          item->setText(tmptable[ridx]);
          ui->tableWidget->setItem(ridx,cidx,item);    
        }    
 }
```

Comment: So what is wrong with that code?

Comment: Perhaps you would want a custom model, and use `QTableView`? Though it will be overall more complex, so above is fine if you are not running into performance problem or something.

Comment: I don't think I'm running into performance problems. It's just a standard QTableWidget shows all entries of a database. Each column of the database is stored in a QList<QString> variable. And I'd like to show all columns into one central QTableWidget. This code above doesn't work propertly, because I got forced close after starting the application (QList out of range). Is there an easy way to merge all QList into one QTableWidget?

Answer (score 0):

I got it running.
This is my final code to add all elements of each QList into the central QTableWidget. It's not that elegant solution. Might be there another (better) solution?

```
for (int cidx = 0; cidx < iColumnCount; cidx++)
{
    if (cidx==0)
    {
        // Column LoginName

        for (int ridx = 0 ; ridx < iRowCount ; ridx++ )
        {
            QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();

            item->setText(ListLoginName[ridx]);
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(ridx,cidx,item);

        }

    }
    if (cidx==1)
    {

        //Column Lastname
        for (int ridx = 0 ; ridx < iRowCount ; ridx++ )
        {
            QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();

            item->setText(ListLastname[ridx]);
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(ridx,cidx,item);

        }

    }
    if (cidx==2)
    {
        // Column Firstname
        for (int ridx = 0 ; ridx < iRowCount ; ridx++ )
        {
            QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();

            item->setText(ListFirstname[ridx]);
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(ridx,cidx,item);

        }

    }
    if (cidx==3)
    {
        // COlumn Position
        for (int ridx = 0 ; ridx < iRowCount ; ridx++ )
        {
            QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();

            item->setText(ListPosition[ridx]);
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(ridx,cidx,item);

        }

    }
    if (cidx==4)
    {
        // Column Email
        for (int ridx = 0 ; ridx < iRowCount ; ridx++ )
        {
            QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();

            item->setText(ListEmail[ridx]);
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(ridx,cidx,item);

        }

    }
    if (cidx==5)
    {
        // Column Telephone
        for (int ridx = 0 ; ridx < iRowCount ; ridx++ )
        {
            QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();

            item->setText(ListTelephone[ridx]);
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(ridx,cidx,item);

        }

    }
}
```